# Exception while opening channel

Tags: c#, wcf

I have instance of class EndpointAddress. Constructor parameter was address which contains German umlaut (net.tcp://süd:8001/EmployeeService) passed though method IdnMapping.GetAscii(string).
Result of that method is net.tcp://xn--sd-xka:8001/EmployeeService.
EndopointAddress class didn't throw exception.
After that I wanted to create instance of DuplexChannelFactory. I have:

```
_factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<ISomeServiceClass>(new InstanceContext(callbackImplementation), binding, endpointAddress);
_channel = _factory.CreateChannel(); 
(_channel as ICommunicationObject).Open();
```

Method Open() throws an exception: No DNS entries exist for host xn--sd-xka.
Had anyone similar problem before? I'm using .net framework 4.0.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried URL encoding the address? You can try with System.Uri.EscapeUriString() or using HttpUtility if you already have references to Web.